# TypeError: bucket.openUploadStream is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage

I was trying to store large files using gridfs to a mongodb database, But I kept this same error again and again "TypeError: bucket.openUploadStream is not a function", Let alone the large files I couldn't stream a text due to this error.

```
const GridFSBucket = require('gridfs-stream');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017').then(()=>
{
    console.log('Database connected')
}).catch(()=>
{
    console.log("Couldn't connect to DB")
})
const grid = async function ()
{
    const bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection, { bucketName: 'my-bucket' });
    const uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream()
    uploadStream.write("This is the file to upload");
    await uploadStream.end();
}
grid();
```

this is the error:
[error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aTyg.png)